# Can I create a script for GIMP to carry out a number of processes?

Tags: image-processing, automation, tesseract, gimp, script-fu

I want to process images before I send them to Tesseract for OCR.

For example:

- Resize the image
- Change the resolution to 300 dpi
- Threshold (B&W image)
- Sharpen image

How can I automate this process?

Comment: Can it be done in GIMP? Yes - but them, maybe a more apropriate library to automate this is Leptonica or VIPS, or even GEGL - both have Python bindings - and that should be your language of choice (even if you choose GIMP, Python-fu would be better than script-fu unless you already know scheme)

Comment: How do I write a script for GIMP in Python-fu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just put together an answer (https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/53919/editing-several-hundred-images-gimp/53965#53965 ) on graphicdesign, which is intended as an GIMP automation primer for people with no programing skills - 
it should  be nice for understanding Python-fu as well.

On the very same answer, there are links to the official documentation, and one example of how to create a small script.  You should them brose GIMP's PDB to findout about the exact proceeds you want.

But, all in all, you can create a Python file like this:

```
from gimpfu import *
import glob

def auto():
    for filename in glob(source_folder  + "/*.png"):
        img = pdb.gimp_file_load(source_folder + filename, source_folder + filename)
        # place the PDB calls to draw on the image before your interation here

        #disp = pdb.gimp_display_new(img)

        pdb.gimp_image_merge_visible_layers(img, CLIP_TO_IMAGE)
        pdb.gimp_file_save(img, img.layers[0], dest_folder + filename, dest_folder + filename)
        # pdb.gimp_display_delete(disp)
        pdb.gimp_image_delete(img)  # drops the image from gimp memory


register("batch_process_for_blah",
         "<short dexcription >Batch Process for Bla",
         "<Extended description text>",
         "author name",
         "license text",
         "copyright note",
         "menu label for plug-in",
         "", # image types for which the plug-in apply - "*" for all, blank for plug-in that opens image itself
         [(PF_DIRNAME, "source_folder", "Source Folder", None),
          (PF_DIRNAME, "dest_folder", "Dest Folder", None)], # input parameters - 
         [], # output parameters
         menu="<Image>/File", # location of the entry on the menus
         )
main()
```

To find the wanted operations inside the `for` loop, go to `Help->Procedure Browser` - or better yet, `Filters->Python->Console` and hit `Browse` - it is almost the same, but with an "apply" button that makes it easy to test the call, and copy it over to your plug-in code.

Comment: How to implement the entire procedure in Python Django ?